# Cauchy in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let {$X_k$} be real-valued random variables on a probability space (Ω, F , P ) that satisfy this in-probability Cauchy condition: for every ε > 0 there exists an integer N < ∞ such that 
$$m,n \ge N \implies P(|X_m-X_n| \ge \epsilon) \le \epsilon $$
How could I show that there is a X such that X_n $\rightarrow$ X in probability.

Comment: Generate a cauchy sequence and use the completeness of $R$ to assume the limit exists.

Comment: I got stuck trying to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/627166/258310

Comment: Can you explain to me what he meant by using catchy-ness implies $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability

Comment: You have to use Borel-Cantelli in the middle to get a subsequence converging a.e. See e.g. [this book‌](https://books.google.com/books?id=hRk_AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&ots=2XZWtW7NI4&dq=convergence%20in%20probability%20cauchy%20complete&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false)​, Theorem 6.1.3. (A. Borovkov, Probability Theory) for a full proof.